# Vue.js FullCalendar v5 component - events not displaying

Tags: javascript, vue.js, events, fullcalendar-5

Recently we have upgraded our FullCalendar component in our Vue.js project from version 4.4.2 to version 5.9.0. However, we have issues with events not displaying. Since I couldn't find why that is in our original file, I have decided to start building calendar in an entirely new file, build the calendar step-by-step in order to hopefully find the error. However, even in this new file, I can't get events to display, and at this point I am completely lost on what am I doing wrong. In the console, I can see the array of events, but I can't get them to be displayed on the calendar.

Here is the code:

```
<template>
    <b-container fluid @click="logEvents">
        <VueFullCalendar :options="calendarOptions" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;" />
    </b-container>
</template>

<script>
import VueFullCalendar from '@fullcalendar/vue'
import resourceTimeGrid from '@fullcalendar/resource-timegrid'
import dayGridPlugin from '@fullcalendar/daygrid'
import timeGridPlugin from '@fullcalendar/timegrid'
import interactionPlugin from '@fullcalendar/interaction'
import listPlugin from '@fullcalendar/list'

export default {
  components: {
    VueFullCalendar
  },
  name: 'Calendar',
  data: function () {
    return {
      calendarOptions: {
        plugins: [dayGridPlugin, timeGridPlugin, interactionPlugin, resourceTimeGrid, listPlugin],
        headerToolbar: {
          left: 'prev,next today',
          center: 'title',
          right: 'dayGridMonth,resourceTimeGridWeek,resourceTimeGridDay'
        },
        initialView: 'resourceTimeGridWeek',
        slotMinTime: '09:00:00',
        slotMaxTime: '21:30:00',
        allDaySlot: false,
        events: [
          {
            title: 'Event 2',
            start: '2021-09-28T09:00',
            end: '2021-09-28T10:30'
          },
          {
            title: 'Event 1',
            start: '2021-09-28T11:00',
            end: '2021-09-28T13:00'
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  methods: {
    logEvents () {
      console.log(this.calendarOptions.events)
    }
  }
}
</script>

<style>

@import '~@fullcalendar/list/main.min.css';
</style>
```

And ideas on what I am doing wrong?

Thank you so much in advance.

Kind regards.

Comment: Same situation here, tried also to load an array of events straight into the `events` property: still nothing

Answer (score -1):

It is all because of date and time format. So, once you manage it, it will be displayed.

```
events: 
[
    { id: 10, title: "All day event", date: new Date('2022-02-25')}
    { id: 20, title: "Timed event", start: new Date(),allDay:true },
    { id: 30, title: "Timed event", start: new Date(),allDay:true },
],
```